# If $f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\,\mathrm d t$ does $f'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $f$ absolute continuous (and $f(0)=0$), i.e. $$f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt$$
for some function $g$. Does $f'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ ?

For example, take $g(x)=\mathbb 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}(x)$, does $$f'(x)=\mathbb  1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}(x)$$ for all $x$ ?

Same, if $$|x|=\tilde f(x)=\int_0^x \text{sgn}(t)dt$$

does $\tilde f'(x)=\text{sgn}(x)$ for all $x$ ?

I have a doubt, because in the case of $f$ for example, then $g(x)=1$ a.e., and thus, $f(x)=x$ a.e., so if $x=2$, then $f'(2)=1\neq \boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}(2)=0$, so I'm not so sure when $f'(x)=g(x)$ or not.

Same with $\tilde f$. For $\tilde f'(x)$ when $x>0$ or $x<0$ it's fine. But what happen in $0$ ? Would it be $0$ ? $-1$ ? $1$ ?

Comment: If $g(x)=\mathbb 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}(x)$ then $f(x)=x$ so $f'(x)=1$. But you do have equality a.s.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Does it mean that $f$ is not derivable at $x\in\mathbb Q$ (in my example ) ?

Comment: It is differentiable everyhere but $f‘(x)-g(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$